# Entity Framework includes not working

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, entity-framework, datagrid

I have some problems with my software. In my Entity Designer I have the following classes:

**Supplier**:
This class holds information about my suppliers and a one-to-many relationship with my Brand-class. Each supplier can have an unlimited number of Brands.

**Brand**
Each Brand belongs to a Supplier, and has a one-to-many relationship with the Product-class.

**Product**
Each product belongs to a brand, and has a one-to-many relationship with StockInformation

**StockInformation**
This class holds information about whether or not a product is in stock.

In my WPF Window, I have three DataGrids, all databound to my three classes.

For the Products-datagrid, I use the following code to retrieve all products:

```
public List<Supplier> GetSuppliers()
{
    return Container.Suppliers.Include("Brands").Include("Brands.Products").Include("Brands.Products.StockInformation").OrderBy(s => s.Name).ToList();
}
```

Also, I have `Container.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;`

However, the problem is that my datagrid tells me that only the first product of each brand is in stock:
(I know this is in Danish, so here are translations:
Navn = Name of each product,
Listepris = Ignore this one,
Antal på lager = How many units currently in stock,
Brand = Brand name)

[image]

I know this isn't correct, as my database says otherwise. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure that this is the first reference to `Container.Suppliers` in the call chain?

Comment: yes. It is the only reference.

Comment: try this `Container.Suppliers.Include("Brands.Products.StockInformation").OrderBy(s => s.Name).ToList();`

Comment: That is what I started with. Tried to solve the problem by changing it to the code in the question. Neither works.

Comment: The code should work. Try creating a brand new context on the line above, just to see if it works ...

Comment: There must be some issue with the configuration of the entities and their relationships.

Comment: I have no idea what is wrong here. Relationships and configuration all looks fine.

Comment: Where so you calculate the stock information? There must be an aggregation somewhere (since `Product` - `StockInformation` is 1:n). Maybe the stock information is tallied per `Supplier`?

Comment: It is calculated in product. Product has a method called GetStock, which does `return StockInformation.Sum(s => s.Count)` Where `Count` is the number of units in stock.

Comment: Hard to imagine that EF gets this wrong if the mappings are OK and the actual FK values match, but what if you try `Container.Products.Include("Brand.Supplier").Include("StockInformation").OrderBy(s => s.Name)` (assuming that the navigation properties exist).

Comment: Have you verified that the actual data item `List<Supplier>` contains the correct information, and that this is a data problem, and not a UI problem? If the data is correct, then can you post the XAML for your DataGrid?

Comment: @Rachel yes, I have. Only the first Product object from each Brand has more than 0 StockInformation objects.

Comment: @GertArnold That actually works! Thank you! Add it as an answer and I'll accept it :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since each row in the grid  represents a `Product`, I would start the query there:

```
Container.Products.Include("Brand.Supplier").Include("StockInformation")
    .OrderB‌​y(s => s.Name).ToList()
```

which of course returns a `List<Product>`.

And apparently, seen your comment, it also solves the issue :).

Comment: I still find this weird. I bet the problem lies in the MySQL Connector.